# I can’t install with pip ("the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted program")

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install `pygame`, but when I try to install it, I get this error:

> ERROR: Error [WinError 225] The operation did not complete
> successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted
> program while executing the command python setup.py egg_info
>
> Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
>
> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 225]
> The operation was not completed successfully because the file contains
> a virus or potentially unwanted program

Also, with `tkinter` and almost all **pip** installations.

I have tried almost every possible method by type:

- Adding antiviruses to the exclusion
- Disabling antiviruses during installation

And anything else related to antiviruses.

Answer (score 0):

## Uninstall anti-virus programs.

For me I was getting the same exact error till I uninstalled all the anti-virus programs and the error was fixed.